# Group rows into a new row and sum in r

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

So I have data that seems like this:

```
 Week        Total Amount        Person
   1            $5                 A
   1            $5                 B
   1            $4                 C
   1            $2                 D
   1            $1                 E
   2            $5                 A
   2            $1                 B
   2            $1                 H
   2            $3                 G
   2            $5                 C
   2            $5                 F
```

How do I make it so that I will show the top 3 for each week and sum all other amounts into "Others"? I want it to show:

```
 Week        Total Amount        Person
   1            $5                 A
   1            $5                 B
   1            $4                 C
   1            $3                 Others
   2            $5                 A
   2            $5                 C
   2            $5                 F
   2            $5                 Others
```

Notice that the other amounts that are not top 3 are summed into a new total amount, and it accounts for the random number of rows for each week (say week 1 has 5 total amounts for each person, but week 2 has 6, and week 3 may be 8 or 10, and week 4 may be 1 total, but I want the equation to apply for each row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(Week) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Total_Amount), .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(Person = case_when(id > 3 ~ "Others",
                            TRUE ~ as.character(Person)))
```

Then remove the $ sign so we can sum the `Total_Amount`:

```
df$Total_Amount <- as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", df$Total_Amount))
```

Finally, sum the `Total_Amount` by group and add the $ sign to bring everything back:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Week, Person) %>% 
  summarise(Total_Amount = sum(Total_Amount)) %>% 
  mutate(Total_Amount = paste0("$", Total_Amount)) %>% 
  select(Week, Total_Amount, Person)
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   Week [2]
   Week Total_Amount Person
  <int>        <chr>  <chr>
1     1           $5      A
2     1           $5      B
3     1           $4      C
4     1           $3 Others
5     2           $5      A
6     2           $5      C
7     2           $5      F
8     2           $5 Others
```

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be using tidyverse. Say this in in a dataframe called df.

```
library(tidyverse)

df.new <- df %>%
  group_by(Week) %>%
  arrange(`Total Amount`) %>%
  mutate(Person = ifelse(row_number() > 3, "Others", Person)) %>%
  group_by(Week, Person) %>%
  summarize(`Total Amount` = sum(`Total Amount`))
```

If there is a "$" in the column (its a string column), you will first need to convert it before you can use the summarize line. You can use a function such as parse_number() to do this.

Comment: nice idea to use `row_number()` ... what I came up with is a bit cranky

`testi<-data.frame(Week=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),
              Total_Amount=c(5,5,4,2,1,5,1,1,3,5,5),
                Person=c("A","B","C","D","E","A","B","H","G","C","F"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

testi_1<-testi%>%group_by(Week)%>%top_n(n = 3,wt=Total_Amount)


testi_2<-testi%>%setdiff(testi_1,testi)%>%group_by(Week)%>%
                  summarise(Total_Amount=sum(Total_Amount),Person="Other")


final<-bind_rows(testi_1,testi_2)`

Answer (score 1):

Base R

```
df$Person[ave(df$`Total Amount`, df$Week, FUN = function(x)
    order(x, decreasing = TRUE)) > 3] = "Others"
df2 = aggregate(df["Total Amount"], df[c("Week", "Person")], sum)
df2[order(df2$Week, df2$Person),]
#  Week Person Total Amount
#1    1      A            5
#3    1      B            5
#4    1      C            4
#7    1 Others            3
#2    2      A            5
#5    2      C            5
#6    2      F            5
#8    2 Others            5
```

**DATA**

```
df = structure(list(Week = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), `Total Amount` = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
5L), Person = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "A", "B", "H", "G", 
"C", "F")), .Names = c("Week", "Total Amount", "Person"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```